# Reasoning for Language-Required Variable Name Prefixes

Tags: language-design

The browser-based software [StudyTRAX](http://www.sciencetrax.com/studytrax) ( http://wiki.studytrax.com ), used for research data management, allows for custom form and form variable management via JavaScript. However, a StudyTRAX "variable" (essentially, a representation of both an element of a form [HTML properties included] and its corresponding parameter, with some data typing/etc.) must be referred to with `#<varname>`, while regular JavaScript variables will just be `<varname>`.

Is this sort of thing done to make parsing easier, or is it just to distinguish between the two so that researchers who aren't so technologically-inclined won't have as much trouble figuring out what they're doing? Given the nature of JavaScript, I would think the StudyTRAX "variables" are just regular JavaScript objects defined in such a way to make form design and customization simpler, and thus the latter would make more sense, but am I wrong?

Also, I know that there are other programming languages that do require specific variable prefixes (though I can't think of some off the top of my head at the moment); what is/was the usual reasoning for that choice in language design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two part answer, StudyTRAX is almost certainly using a preprocessor to do some magic.  JavaScript makes this relativity easy, but not as easy as a Lisp would.  You still need to parse the code. By prefixing, the parser can ignore a lot of the complicated syntax of JavaScript and get to the good part without needing a "picture perfect" compiler.  Actually, a lot of templeting systems do this.  It is an implementation of Lisp's quasi-quote ([see Greenspun's Tenth Rule](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GreenspunsTenthRuleOfProgramming)).

As for prefixes in general, the best way to understand them is to try to write a parser for a language without them.  For very dynamic and pure languages like Lisp and JavaScript where everything is a List / object it is not too bad.  When you get languages where methods are distinct from objects, or functions are not first class the parser begins having to ask itself what type of thing doe "foo" refer to?  An annoying example from Ruby:  an unprefixed identifier is either a local variable or a method implicitly on `self`.  In Rails there are a few functions that are implemented with `method_missing`.  `Person.find_first_by_rank` works fine, but

```
Class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def promotion(name)
    p = find_first_by_rank
    [...]
  end
end
```

gives an error because `find_first_by_rank` looks like it might be a local variable and Ruby is scared to call `method_missing` on something that might just be a misspelled local variable.

Now imagine trying to distinguish between instance variables (prefix-@), class-variables (prefix-@@), global variables (prefix-$), Constants (first letter Capitol), method names and local variables (no prefix small case) by context alone.

Comment: comingstorm's answer was nice, but I really like yours. Thanks for the more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

(From a Compiler & Language Hobbyst Designer).

Your question is more especific to the "StudyTRAX" software.

In early days of programming, variables in Basic used prefixes as $ (for strings, "a$"), to difference from numeric values. Today, some programming languages such as PHP prefixes variables with "$". COBNOL used variables starting with A to I, for integers, and later letters for floats.

Transforming, and later, executing some code, its a complex task, that's why many programmers, use shortcuts like adding prefixes or suffixes to programming languages.

In many Collegues or Universities, exist specialized classes / courses for transforming code from a programming language, to something that the computer does, like "Compilers", "Automatons", "Language Design", because its not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Perl requires different variable prefixes, depending on the type of data:

```
$scalar = 4.2;
@array = (1, 4, 9, 16);
%map = ("foo" => 42, "bar" => 17, "baz" => 137);
```

As I understand it, this is so the reader can immediately identify what kind of object they're dealing with.  It's not a matter of whether the reader is technologically inclined or not:  if you reduce the programmer's cognitive load, he can use his brainpower for more important things than figuring out fiddly syntactic details.

Whether Perl's design is successful in this respect is another question, but I believe that's the reasoning behind the feature.

Comment: That makes sense, considering many IDEs these days offer the same sort of functionality for the variables of the language said IDE's support (well, for statically-typed languages, at least, though an interpreted environment could provide contextual support for dynamic typing as well). Does Perl do it just for general types of variables rather than specific types (i.e. integers and floating-point values are both $scalar)? Haven't really had any experience with it yet.

Comment: Yes: integers, floating point values, strings, and references all count as scalar in Perl, and require `$varname` syntax.